# Why does $wpdb return strings for mysql integer values?

Tags: database, wpdb, customization

I find it very inconvenient and hard to understand that the default behavior of the Wordpress db-interface is to convert all integer (and float?) types to strings.

e.g

```
$wp_posts = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * from wp_posts');
$unexpected_type = gettype($wp_posts[0]->ID)  == 'string';
```

Please confirm my suspicion that this is done in order to support very large (capacious) integer types that are not supported by PHP, or provide an alternative explanation as to why one would chose to convert integers to strings.

The second part of my question, as maybe expected, is to find out if there is a built in configuration parameter to the `wpdb` class that would allow one to request *integers* for integer-type records.

Comment: Have you [read source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/wp-db.php)?

Comment: Frankly no, I was hoping to save some time.

Comment: I think is the expected behaviour of the PHP mysql commands, so maybe you should check the PHP manual as well.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317938/2078474) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852814/mysql-query-returns-only-string-type-for-int-fload-db-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the MySQL interface library used prior to PHP 5.3 returns everything as strings. The new (optional) interface, MySQL Native Driver, can return integer types if enabled at compile time.

For details, look into libmysql and mysqlnd.

Comment: For mysqlnd at least, native types are only returned when using prepared statements, and unfortunately $wpdb does not.

Answer (score 4):

As the other people have mentioned in the comments, due to the libraries that source uses, strings are returned. If you need to convert to an integer for a comparison or function call, just use WordPress's [`absint`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/absint) function .

```
$int_id = absint( $wp_posts[0]->ID );
```

Also, not sure if your DB call is just simply an example, but I suggest using [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), or better yet, a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if possible. This allows you to maintain all of the sanitization those functions have built into them, keeping the security of your site pretty solid. Also remember to use [`wp_reset_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) after using the above to methods to ensure you are reverting back to the main loop.

Comment: Wordpress posts have nothing to do with the question, but thank you for the informative answer.

Comment: Yes, I figured it was just example code, but just thought I'd toss it in anyways :)

Comment: In cases where you have an array of numeric strings (like from a `get_col()` result), you can cast them all to ints with something like this: `$user_ids = array_map( 'absint', $user_ids );`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
sudo service apache2 restart
```